# Can't cast enum to int dot42

Tags: c#, android, dot42

I'm evaluating the use of dot42 framework to target android using C#.. 
So while going through what dot42 can and can't do, I got stuck with the following casting not working.. throws Java expression error.

```
 public enum Days { Sat = 1, Sun, Mon }

 Days day = Days.Sun;
 int dayNumber = (int)day; // <----- Throws Error
```

Is there any way around this ?

Thanks...

Comment: It is a simple and common mistake, easy to find on google...

Comment: `int dayNumber = day.ordinal();`

Comment: I think it's not that easy to find it on Google because I've been searching for 2 days.

ordinal method doesn't exist and I have the latest dot42 framework.

Thanks anyway...

Comment: Forgot to say that ...
This type of casting is being neglected by the dot42 convertal for some reason..
so the whole line is not ported into the apk.

I can get to the error using watches or Convert.ToInt32(day);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are on version 1.0.0.70?

The following test code runs OK here.

```
namespace TestDays
{
    [Activity]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance) 
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
            testDays();
            SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);
        }

                public enum Days { Sat = 1, Sun, Mon }

        public int testDays() 
        {
            Days day = Days.Sun;
            int dayNumber = (int)day; // <----- Throws Error
            return dayNumber;
        }

   }
}
```

*Disclosure:  I work for dot42.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.. Your code works.

Now, The way I see it that variables which are never used are being omitted through the conversion..

this doesn't work :

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
        {
            Days day = Days.Sun;
            int dayNumber = (int)day; 

            base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
            SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);
        }
....

Comment: but this does :

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
        {
            Days day = Days.Sun;
            int dayNumber = (int)day; 
            dayNumber++; // any expression with the variable

            base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
            SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);
        }


If you have the time to shed some lights on this issue. That would be nice of you.

Appreciate your help..